# Is it allowed to write a SQL function in Oracle to return more than data types?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I am trying to understand about SQL functions in Oracle, I was wondering if it is possible to write a SQL function which can return a Number or a Varchar2 based on the conditions in the program.

Comment: of course it is possible

Comment: Are you referring to the [CREATE FUNCTION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370) statement?

Comment: A function can only return one datatype; but that can be a scalar data type (e.g. number *or* varchar2) or a collection or a ref cursor. If you want to change the data type of the returned value then I guess you could use a ref cursor, but the caller still has to know what to expect. If the caller knows before the call based on a flag it passes in then you could overload the function instead. It isn't really clear what you actual aim is here though.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for clarifying, I want to know if we can return more than one datatypes. For example, if arg I passed is 'abc' then it should return a value of data type Number else it should return value with Varchar2 datatype.

Comment: You can't change the scalar data type returned, no. You can overload but the caller has to know which version to call. But like I said, the caller would have to know what to expect anyway.

Comment: You cannot make the return type generic as you are expecting, however you can use object type and store the result accordingly with different column and return the object type.

Comment: Well.. there's [ANYTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5A8C5AC6-BC32-4D78-B0DE-037162106C72) I suppose, but not sure you want to go down that route either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can SORT OF do that using a return type of ANYDATA.  But the calling query or PL/SQL block would have to use a CASE statement to evaluate the return type in order to do anything with it.  Very simple demonstration below.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AnyData_Test
      (
       p_Value_In            IN      VARCHAR2
      )
      RETURN AnyData
AS
      ad_Test_Var            ANYDATA;
BEGIN
      CASE
            WHEN p_Value_In = 'Varchar2' THEN ad_Test_Var := SYS.ANYDATA.ConvertVarchar2('VC2');
            WHEN p_Value_In = 'Number'   THEN ad_Test_Var := SYS.ANYDATA.ConvertNumber(123);
            ELSE                              ad_Test_Var := SYS.ANYDATA.ConvertDate(SYSDATE);
      END CASE;
      RETURN ad_Test_Var;
END AnyData_Test;
/

SELECT
      AnyData.GetTypeName(AnyData_Test('Varchar2'))    AS Return_Type_V
     ,AnyData.AccessVarchar2(AnyData_Test('Varchar2')) AS Return_Type_V_Value
     --
     ,AnyData.GetTypeName(AnyData_Test('Number'))      AS Return_Type_N
     ,AnyData.GetTypeName(AnyData_Test('Nope'))        AS Return_Type_D
FROM dual
;
      
SELECT
      CASE AnyData.GetTypeName(AnyData_Test('Varchar2'))
            WHEN 'SYS.VARCHAR2' THEN AnyData.AccessVarchar2(AnyData_Test('Varchar2'))
            ELSE 'Other'
      END AS Quick_Test
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Ah, perhaps someone can cleanup the formatting for me; can't determine why it insists on displaying as a garbled mess?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle functions can be as complex as you want , and you can apply as much logic as you want. A very basic example of a function with logic inside

- The function only admits two parameters, one as varchar and other as number
- C2 can only be A or B. Other value is an error
- The function based on that returns a number which is the sum of c1 +10 if it is A, +100 if it is B.

Let's make it work

```
SQL> create or replace function my_example ( c1 in number , c2 in varchar2 ) return 
number
is
        begin
        if c2 = 'A'
        then
           return c1 + 10 ;
        elsif c2 = 'B'
        then
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9             return c1 + 100 ;
        else
           raise_application_error ( -20001, 'c1 only allows A or B' );
 10   11   12   end if;
end;
 13   14  /

Function created.

SQL> select my_example( 1 , 'A' ) from dual ;

MY_EXAMPLE(1,'A')
-----------------
               11

SQL>  select my_example( 1 , 'B' ) from dual ;

MY_EXAMPLE(1,'B')
-----------------
              101

SQL>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to return either numbers of strings, use return varchar2

```
SQL> create or replace function my_example ( c1 in number , c2 in varchar2 ) return varchar2
  2  is
  3     begin
        if c2 = 'A'
        then
           return c1 + 10 ;
  4    5    6    7      elsif c2 = 'B'
  8     then
  9        return c1 + 100 ;
 10     elsif c2= 'C'
        then
                return 'Alfa' ;
 11   12   13   else
           raise_application_error ( -20001, 'c1 only allows A or B' );
        end if;
end;
/ 14   15   16   17

Function created.

SQL> select my_example( 1 , 'C' ) from dual ;

MY_EXAMPLE(1,'C')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alfa

SQL> select my_example( 1 , 'A' ) from dual ;

MY_EXAMPLE(1,'A')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11

SQL>  select my_example( 1 , 'B' ) from dual ;

MY_EXAMPLE(1,'B')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101
```

Then you can also apply ( 12.2 onwards ) the `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` standard function to determine whether the return of the original function is a string or a number

```
SQL> select validate_conversion ( my_example( 1 , 'B' ) as number ) from dual ;

VALIDATE_CONVERSION(MY_EXAMPLE(1,'B')ASNUMBER)
----------------------------------------------
                                             1

SQL> select validate_conversion ( my_example( 1 , 'C' ) as number ) from dual ;

VALIDATE_CONVERSION(MY_EXAMPLE(1,'C')ASNUMBER)
----------------------------------------------
                                             0

SQL>
```

1 means true number, 0 means it is not a number

Comment: How to return `'Alfa'`, for example if C2 is 'C'.

Comment: answer updated. I would really appreciate if you accept the answer or upvote it, or both if you consider so

Comment: The function in the "UPDATE" section of this answer returns a varchar2. (Not - quoted from the question - : "a Number or a Varchar2 based on the conditions in the program")
From the documentation: "VALIDATE_CONVERSION determines whether expr can be converted to the specified data type."  
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD
The code snippet proves that the function's return value can be _converted_ to a NUMBER.

Comment: Indeed ,in the update returns a varchar2, that can be easily converted to a  number when the value is actually a number,. VALLDATE_CONVERSION just was a way to show how can be used to prove whether is a number or not . That's it